# merge arrays PHP (slice)

Tags: php, merge, slice

I have an this array (i show it here as a json..):

```
[
{
"icon1_name":"Home Address A",
"icon2_name":"Home Address B",
"icon3_name":"Home addressC",
},
{
"icon1_name":"OfficeA",
"icon2_name":"OfficeB",
"icon3_name":"OfficeC",
}
```

]

I'm trying to add an array in the middle (between home address and office).
This what i tried to do:

```
array_splice( $myArray, 1, 0, $arrayToInsert );
```

But i get the result with numbers:

```
    {
    "1":{
    "icon1_name":"OfficeA",
    "icon2_name":"OfficeB",
    "icon3_name":"OfficeC",
    "
    },
  "2":{
    "icon1_name":"PhoneA",
    "icon2_name":"PhoneB",
    "icon3_name":"PhoneC",
    "
    },
    "3":{
    "icon1_name":"FaxA",
    "icon2_name":"FaxB",
    "icon3_name":"FaxC",
    }}
```

How can i do this merge without getting it numbered? Thats mean, keep the original json format.

Comment: What do you mean without getting it numbered?

Comment: Look at the second JSON. its not the same. Its has array numbers: "1","2","3"...

Comment: You could call array_values on the array in php which would reset the numbers back to starting with `0` and when converted to json make the outter array an array, not an object.

Comment: @jonathankuhn nice, you should make it an answer

Comment: @nl-x I could, but it really isn't ideal. The real answer should be how to not have the problem in the first place. But it does work. I just don't have the time (at work) to debug and fix it so I generally just throw up quick comments with quick fixes.

Comment: Are the trailing commas in your JSON objects typos? Ex.: `"icon3_name":"FaxC",`.

Comment: Documentation on array_splice says "Note that numeric keys in input are not preserved."

Comment: I was just about to say what @nl-x said. The numeric keys are not preserved meaning that they will be automatically reset to 0-N. Also, I did have some time to play with it and couldn't reproduce the problem. [example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jD6gdP). I'm assuming you are unsetting the `0` key somewhere. Or else you could just do what I said above and use array_values which will reset the keys. If this doesn't help, you would need to show more code to get an answer. Or if you are unsetting the `0` key, use array_shift instead.

Comment: If you are converting the JSON to an array via json_decode or some other function, I would try doing a print_r on the array before the splice.  If the array shows the numeric indices, it is not an array_splice problem but a conversion problem.  It looks to me like your JSON doesn't represent a single array but an array of arrays.  Note the two sets of curly braces {}; each of these looks like an independent array.

Comment: @AngusAtkins-Trimnell It is an array of arrays. Or to be more accurate, in json it is an array of objects. Square brackets on the outside and curly braces on the inside. And a print_r will always show a numeric key, the problem is that the keys are not in consecutive order starting with `0`. When that happens, php will assume you have an associative array with numbers as indices and json convert to an object instead of an array. Note that in this case, I am saying that an array with the keys 10, 20, 30...etc is an assoc array because they don't start with 0 and are not consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

The `array_splice` code you posted works fine with the JSON strings decoded as here:

```
$myArray = json_decode('[
    {
        "icon1_name":"Home Address A",
        "icon2_name":"Home Address B",
        "icon3_name":"Home addressC"
    },
    {
        "icon1_name":"OfficeA",
        "icon2_name":"OfficeB",
        "icon3_name":"OfficeC"
    }
]');

$arrayToInsert = json_decode('[
    {
        "icon1_name":"PhoneA",
        "icon2_name":"PhoneB",
        "icon3_name":"PhoneC"
    }
]');

array_splice( $myArray, 1, 0, $arrayToInsert );

print_r( json_encode($myArray) );
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "icon1_name":"Home Address A",
    "icon2_name":"Home Address B",
    "icon3_name":"Home addressC"
  },
  {
    "icon1_name":"PhoneA",
    "icon2_name":"PhoneB",
    "icon3_name":"PhoneC"
  },
  {
    "icon1_name":"OfficeA",
    "icon2_name":"OfficeB",
    "icon3_name":"OfficeC"
  }
]
```

Are the JSON strings you're decoding into PHP arrays different than these?